# Infinite sequences with all but finitely many elements equal

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider two infinite sequences $\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2,\dots\}$ such that $0<|a_i|<1$, $0<|b_i|<1$, $|a_i|\geq|b_i|$ for all $i$ and $a_i=b_i$ for all except finitely many $i$. Now consider the two products $\prod_i a_i$ and $\prod_i b_i$ and note that both these products tend to 0 as $i\to\infty$. I am trying to understand whether the following argument holds (or something similar to this): There exists sequence $\{c_1,c_2,\dots\}$ such that $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\prod_i \frac{a_i}{c_i}\neq0$ and $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\prod_i \frac{b_i}{c_i}=0$. (If $a_i\neq b_i$ for infinitely many $i$ the result holds immediately by picking $a_i=c_i$ for all $i$.)

Comment: Perhaps, you need $b_i \neq 0$. Take $a_1=0.5$, $b_1=0$ and $a_i=b_i=c_i=0.5$

Comment: Why do you think $\prod_ia_i\to0$?

Comment: The condition $|a_i|<1$ is not sufficient for $\prod_i a_i $ to converge to zero.

Comment: In any case, the only way to have $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\prod_i \frac{a_i}{c_i}\neq0$ but $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\prod_i \frac{b_i}{c_i}=0$ when eventually $a_i=b_i$ is for some $b_i$ before that point to be zero, since the quotient of those limits is simply the product of the finitely many quotients that differ from $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I have to add that both $a_i$ and $b_i$ are bounded away from zero (I will edit the question on that). Regarding the other comment, my idea why both of products go to zero is as follows: $|a_i|=1-\epsilon_i$ for some $\epsilon_i>0$. Taking the infimum $\epsilon$ over all $\epsilon_i$ I get that $|a_i|<1-\epsilon$, therefore $\prod_i^n a_i\leq \prod_i^n |a_i|<(1-\epsilon)^n$ for all $n$, but $(1-\epsilon)^n$ goes to 0 as $n\to\infty$. Analogously, I can bound it from below.

Comment: Please, let me know if there is some logical mistake on the argument.

Comment: That infimum $\epsilon$ may well be $0$.

Comment: For lots of examples of this, see [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Examples) at Wikipedia.

Comment: I see...If we assume that this is not the case and indeed the two products go to zero, you still believe though that we could not make this claim, no?

Comment: See my first comment above in that regard; it's not affected by that condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input.